# Store instances of a generic class in a map while keeping them typed correctly

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript I would like to store instances of a generic class (here class `Foo`) in a `Map`.

However, I do not get the desired results since the map values are (obviously) not typed correctly since the use of `any`. Is there any way to get it done?

I am not sure about using `Record` or type aliases might be worth a look.

```js
class Foo<T> {
  t: T;
}

class Bar {

  // Use of any because I am not sure about the right way
  map: Map<string, any> = new Map();
}

const bar = new Bar();

bar.map.set('numberEntry', new Foo<number>());
bar.map.set('stringEntry', new Foo<string>());

const n = bar.map.get('numberEntry').t;
const s = bar.map.get('stringEntry').t;

console.log(typeof n); // undefined; should be 'number'
console.log(typeof s); // undefined; should be 'string'
```

Please let me know if further details are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `typeof n` is runtime check, and we have here runtime issue, as our Foo instances have no values in field `t`. There is no assignment of this field in the code. `new Foo<number>()` creates `Foo` instance with `undefined` t field. We need to pass somehow t. We can fix it in the following way:

```
class Foo<T> {
  t: T;
  constructor(t: T) {
    this.t = t;
  }
}
```

---

Now about typying and using `any`.

If we use `Set` then it is not possible to match key of the set with particular value type.  We can say that this set have some possible types, in this example it would be:

```
Map<string, Foo<string | number>> = new Map();
```

[Full working code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=24&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3gKGtALgFzQoDcu0w8AdhPgE4Cuw+89AFESQJRYV74AFgEsIAOnzQAvAXJ4AvtkXZQkGACEw9PhQD0u6AFUIAU2jwAZtDDUAntABGJ4GEanoASWsBbaNXiSEIz0ZmAO8IySQmb0wgDmgpIA7mC2FN5gAA7EALJZSHSx1HEANHCIBQzCxdAAPn6M3k70aBgy1CZJ0HmZ7NzkylS0kg5a0n6d0Joc-djYo-RiGZlipvjsAOTUjc0AotQMthtlHV0IyNtNJi3sAIzcswtLWasm6xuF1XH7h8cTZxVPsU0OwAERgUEPcgqGh0PzjJ7LMRxN6bS57A70I7cAD8EnIQzhMBkiJeKPeQO+mOxePw0MJ8BAJjEIHgcU4tkyJksfn60H00EY1AAJiYLNUTMLSNAIIIIiBhY4zFsdtcNjDaIzmaz2fhOdyrBA+QKhaLxR0pTK5YwFUroB8qsV1UA)

So we are saying in our Map we store values of `Foo` with either `string` or `number` fields.

---

BTW. If we want to have key -> value type relation we should use POJO:

```
const map: {
  numberEntry: Foo<number>;
  stringEntry: Foo<string>;
} = {
  numberEntry: new Foo(1),
  stringEntry: new Foo("a")
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first thing is clear so far, I should have had mentioned this in my question. However, looks like I'm going to use some kind of union type, though I hoped to get it done otherwise. The idea with the POJO is pretty neat. I will take a closer look at this one catching up with my requirements in detail :)